# method for backup and purging wso2 metrics data

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

While using REST client method for collecting analytics in wso2 apim 1.10 using DAS 3.0.1, what is the best way to take backup and purge the database? i'm planning below approach for backup and file size issues. Please let me know if there is a better approach.

1)Take backup of existing database every hour/day.  By writing some code i'll send hourly/daily data to other database(this db is different and not configured in wso2).
2) Purge data for every hourly/daily.
3) Also will there be any impact to apim performance if we purge data on regular basis?